# Smooth line with a condition

Tags: qgis

I have a curvy polygon and a line. I want to smooth the line as much as possible, but so that it does not go beyond the polygon. I used the Smooth tool and my line went outside the polygon. Is there any way to adjust the condition - smooth it as much as possible, but not go beyond the polygon?

This is my polygon. The yellow one is the source line and the red one is a smooth line
[image]

Comment: By its very nature, smoothing is going to cut corners. Maybe what you really want is to compute the centerline of the polygon.

Comment: When you say you want "to smooth the line as much as possible", what do you actually mean? For example, the yellow line in your example can be made smoother, but it will make it longer. Or do you actually want the shortest line? Or something else. Consider adding the background of the underlying problem you are trying to solve as it will be more likely to get you alternative answers.